# Are any of these worthy of an historical lock?

Tags: discussion, historical-lock

Of the [24 closed questions on SO with more than 500 votes](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed%3A1+votes%3A500), [8 have historical locks](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed%3A1+votes%3A500+locked%3A1) on them and [16 do not](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed%3A1+votes%3A500+locked%3A0).

If you look into these, you’ll find that many are quite old, but closed relatively recently. I believe that this reflects historical changes in what was considered an ok question or not. They used to be considered ok, but no longer are.

Some of these are also well on their way to deletion. Before that happens, this seems like a good place to consider whether an historical lock might not be worth applying.

I noticed this because I noticed this question:

- [What can I use to profile C++ code in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux)

already had 1 out of 10 delete votes on it, despite having an over-500 answer and several other highly voted answers.  Plus I got to that question coming from another similar question:

- [Alternatives to gprof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777556/alternatives-to-gprof)

That one already has 8 out of 10 delete votes. Sure, it doesn’t have an over-500 vote, but it was still enough for a Great Answer badge in its day.  Should we lock it instead of giving it the 2 more votes for the *coup de grace*?

I’d like to make sure that we really want to delete questions like these from our system.  Some of the over-500’s aren’t really worth keeping around, but some I believe are, and I would rather they didn’t slip away by accident.  It’s too hard to search for them once they’re gone.

To that end, here’s [the current set](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed%3A1+votes%3A500+locked%3A0) of closed but unlocked questions with over 500 votes each:

- [How do I get started with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js) [closed] 
  1260 votes, 3 answers; asked mar 1 '10
- [How do emulators work and how are they written?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448673/how-do-emulators-work-and-how-are-they-written) [closed] 
  961 votes, 16 answers; asked jan 15 '09
- [Using a piano keyboard as a computer keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928061/using-a-piano-keyboard-as-a-computer-keyboard) [closed] 
  692 votes, 35 answers; asked may 8 '11
- [Interview question: f(f(n)) == -n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731832/interview-question-ffn-n) [closed] 
  665 votes, 113 answers; asked apr 8 '09
- [How do I commit all deleted files in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402776/how-do-i-commit-all-deleted-files-in-git) [duplicate] 
  619 votes, 6 answers; asked sep 10 '09
- [Looking for a better JavaScript unit test tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300855/looking-for-a-better-javascript-unit-test-tool) [closed] 
  610 votes, 21 answers; asked nov 19 '08
- [Is < faster than <=?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135518/is-faster-than) [closed] 
  585 votes, 14 answers; asked aug 27 '12
- [Python progression path - From apprentice to guru](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573135/python-progression-path-from-apprentice-to-guru) [closed] 
  575 votes, 19 answers; asked apr 4 '10
- [Best way to parse command line arguments in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491595/best-way-to-parse-command-line-arguments-in-c) [closed] 
  566 votes, 21 answers; asked jan 29 '09
- [What can I use to profile C++ code in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux) [closed] 
  559 votes, 21 answers; asked dec 17 '08
- [Java: iterate through HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066589/java-iterate-through-hashmap) [duplicate] 
  553 votes, 7 answers; asked jun 30 '09
- [Text editor to open big (giant, huge, large) text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159521/text-editor-to-open-big-giant-huge-large-text-files) [closed] 
  547 votes, 49 answers; asked oct 1 '08
- [Getting started with Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012573/getting-started-with-haskell) [closed] 
  540 votes, 15 answers; asked jun 18 '09
- [How do I improve the performance of SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711631/how-do-i-improve-the-performance-of-sqlite) [closed] 
  532 votes, 5 answers; asked nov 10 '09
- [A better Java JSON library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library) [closed] 
  529 votes, 20 answers; asked dec 3 '08
- [UIImagePickerController, UIImage, Memory and More?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282830/uiimagepickercontroller-uiimage-memory-and-more) [closed] 
  503 votes, 6 answers; asked aug 16 '09

The two duplicates should probably be merged rather than deleted. But what about the others?

Comment: I'd vote for keeping the two dups. Duplicates are supposed to be "signposts" pointing to a different question if you didn't search for the exact term, and seeing as these questions have over 500 upvotes, I'd say they are serving their purpose fairly well.

Comment: as far as I can tell, all the questions you listed "meet Jeff Atwood's 3rd rule" mentioned in [historical-lock tag wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/historical-lock/info) by a wide margin: _"Does this question teach me anything that could make me better at my job? Can I learn something from it?"_ In this regard, these are fairly strong candidates for lock.

Comment: @gnat That’s what I was thinking. This came up because I found delete votes on some I thought worth keeping. Two have 8/10 delete votes on them, and at least one has 5/10 delete votes on it. Rather than just flagging for a mod to lock them, I thought it better to come here and ask whether they were worth saving.

Comment: @Doorknob I meant as opposed to deleting them. I do understand the many-paths notion, I just didn’t want to see them deleted altogether, at least not without some further discussion than a vote provides.

Comment: I flagged [one of the listed questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448673/how-do-emulators-work-and-how-are-they-written "this one") for mod attention, referring to that very post and asking to address it. Will see how it goes

Comment: the question I flagged and _get started with Node.js_ are now locked; the rest in the list is not (yet?)

Comment: I'm the author of the upvoted answer on [*Alternatives to `gprof`*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1779343/23771), that lists a lot of valid reasons why people find `gprof` less than satisfactory. I'm trying to attribute helpful motives to those who voted to delete.